# How can i use $gte with other values in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

How can I do something similar to the following piece of code using Mongoose:

```
"filter":{"custom_fields.ram": {"$in": [1.2, {"$gte":1.8}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using it like this, you can do it like this:

```
"filter":{"custom_fields.ram": {"$or": [{"$in": [1.2]}, {"$gte":1.8}]}}
```